# Putty command to find files that are not named in Roman letters

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, find, putty

I need a command through Putty or something to find any file in my server that isn't named in Roman alphabet.  So the result of the command gives me the path of the file(s) that match this.

My website's server uses Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1.

And I want to search in this path (/var/www/) and all sub-folders of it.

Comment: Darn, I had this great answer, then I realized you didn't mean "files that are not named in Roman numbers"...

Answer (score 0):

This should work to find files and directories in your `/var/www` which contain characters other than upper/lowercase A to Z:

```
find /var/www -iregex '^[.]*[/A-Za-z]*$' -o -print
```

Leave out the `-o` to see what it *is* matching.
The leading `[.]*` lets you use `find . -iregexp`... without needing to change the regexp; you can drop it for the `/var/www` case.

You might need to adjust the `[A-Za-z]` if you mean classical Roman, which didn't have J, U, or W.

I still liked my erroneous first interpretation, where I thought you were looking for files which weren't named with roman *numbers*, which had a solution along the lines of:

```
find /var/www -iregex '^[.]*\(/\|/m*c?d?x?c*x?l?i*x?i?v?i*\)*$' -o -print
```

(same note on "[.]" as on the prior example)

If you're really looking for filenames containing non-ASCII characters:

```
find /var/www -iregex '^[ -~]+$'  -o -print
```

That one doesn't need the "[.]" at the front because "." is part of the range anyway.

Or non-ISO-8859-1 (which includes a number of non-Latin, but no asian, hindi, etc):

```
find /var/www -iregex '^[ -ÿ]+$'  -o -print    # note the dieresis over the "y"
```

Comment: this still lists all the file in the directory!  Here is an example: add some files named: file1, file2, file3 to a directory, and also add an Arabic lettered filename like ملف.  What I need is to show only that Arabic file only, and not all the list

Comment: That's because your file{1,2,3} have characters which aren't "Roman letters" (the 1, 2, and 3).  Did you mean you wanted names which contain non-ASCII and non-ISO-8859-1 as well?

Comment: the last 3 variants you added gives an error: "find: Invalid range end"

Comment: I'm using a fairly modern version of find (from GNU findutils 4.4.2) on Ubuntu 12.04 (a 2012 release), so it's possible your version is different.  Stuff the output of "find --version" in here, and your operating system flavor and version, and we'll see if that's the issue.

Comment: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2 - and I use putty to search the server

Comment: Maybe the OP wanted to include dots (for extensions), numbers, spaces and maybe dashes?

Comment: He'd only need to add some more characters in the first example's regexp.  For your case (spaces are annoying enough to not include), with the caveat that "-" is tricky to avoid defining a range, use:  find . -iregex '^[.]*[/A-Za-z0-9.-]*$' -o -print